# Assigning part of an if statement to a variable

Tags: wordpress, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is it possible to assign

```
get_theme_mod('dds') !== 'false';
```

to a variable and include it in an if statement instead of typing the whole thing?

This is the if statement I am dealing with:

```
$DDS = get_theme_mod('dds') !== 'false';

if( is_category() && $DDS ) :
    //output some css style
endif;
```

I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get error because of you are not complete if statement **bracket** see below code to remove error.

```
$DDS = get_theme_mod('dds') !== 'false';

if( is_category() && $DDS ) :
    //output some css style
endif;
```

**Another solution:** no need to make variable you can direct add code in **if** condition you get same solution as above code

```
if( is_category() && ( get_theme_mod('dds') !== 'false' ) ) :
   //output some css style
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks, I over looked the bracket in the if statement. I will be reusing that condition a lot, so I just wanted to write $DDS instead of typing the thing every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `!= false` at all, seems redundant?